# How to incorporate Bootstrap3 into phonegap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, windows-8, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am working on developing application that will work for web, tablet and also mobile , windows8 etc. Is there any examples  of site that i can refer to what modification I need to make to make 
bootstrap 3  work in phonegap and with other aswell.
I want to keep same look and feel for responsive web part, but same look for throughout tablet , mobile, windows 8 live and window9 phone etc..

I prolly dont need to use the responsive part of bootstrap within phonegap.  Has anyone also used bootstrap for all platforms? any examples and solution would be really appreciated

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Phonegap solutions are html/js/css projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using Bootstrap with Cordova 3.1 and iOS 7, also using jQM at the same time to achieve certain things. Zero problems to report about that.

On the other hand Cordova will not impede this integration, remember that Cordova is a set of device APIs that allow a mobile app developer to access native device functions. Cordova does not solve the UI side so you can choose to use the one that best fits you.

Just start a cordova project and include the JS, CSS and other bootstrap resources within your home page. Be aware to not include the bootstrap file in each of your pages if you are going to use jQM also.

The only thing that can crash a bit is the other JS libraries that you could start integrating to solve the UI side like JQM or other libraries to do special stuff. But they could work pretty smooth.

What is confusing is that you want to use bootstrap but don´t want the responsive features. If you want to have the exactly same look and structure don´t use bootstrap, code it by yourself with plain HTML and CSS so nothing is responsive. Bear in mind that it could be very hard to maintain the exact look and feel & structure across all devices as they have different screens and resolutions. Moreover it could be not useful or friendly to have an app with very small buttons or fonts in a smartphone just to maintain the same structure in all devices. So responsiveness is a great help IMHO.

AFAIK you don't have to disable bootstrap stuff to work with cordova. Probably only if you are using something that could crash like variables names, declarations.

Just start working with bootstrap and cordova. No serious problems will arise.